# The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic error

Tags: java, generics, apache-poi, import-from-excel

I am trying to read an .xlsx file using Apache POI. The jar files I added to the build path are:

```
poi-3.12-20150511.jar
poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

I am now using this readFromExcel method:

```
public void readFromExcel(){


    String excelFilePath = "Books.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));


     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

     XSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

     Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();


        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                }
                System.out.print(" - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

Now I am gettting these two errors:

> The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
>   The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Comment: Can you post your imports? Only it looks to me like you've imported the wrong type

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row.getCell()` method.
Try this:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(yourFile.getInputstream());

 Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);//1,2,3

 Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            row.getCell(0);
            row.getCell(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've imported the wrong Iterator!

In your imports section, you must have something like:

```
import blah.blah.HTMLDocument.Iterator;
```

You need to change that to the correct one, [java.util.Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), eg

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

You've also made a few other mistakes too... As [explained here in the POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), if you have a `File`, give that to POI, not a `FileInputStream`!

Secondly, you can use for-each iteration, as [detailed here in the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), eg

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
      ...
```

Then you don't even need to explicitly use an iterator to start with!